# How to closing another swing program which have JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE from a program without terminating main(calling) program

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am creating an IDE using swing which can compile and run user's program. if user write swing program and run the program which have `frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);` inside that program, it successfully run. but when user close there program, my IDE also get closed. How to get rid from this. I want that my IDE don't get closed.

Is there any procedure that my swing application still get running when user close there program?

For Example: in Netbeans IDE, when we run a swing program and close that program, Netbeans IDE does not get closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could change their close operation to something else such as DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE or DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE.

i.e.,

```
OtherGUI otherGui = new OtherGui();
otherGui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
otherGui.setVisible(true);
```

As an aside, you might want to tell us more about your current design of running other programs, as that makes me worry about possible issues. What exactly are you doing?

---

**Edit**
You state:

> actually i am running that program via reflection and i don't have right to change user program, so what should i do in such case?

and

> I am creating an IDE using swing which can compile and run user's program. if user write swing program and run the program which have frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); inside that program, it successfully run. but when user close there program, my IDE also get closed. How to get rid from this. I want that my IDE don't get closed.

I've no experience with this, but I suspect that you will want to create each launched GUI in its own JVM, which you'd do not with reflection (I don't think), but by creating a new process with a ProcessBuilder, taking care to handle all streams appropriately, and calling Java directly in your process, launching the program.

Comment: actually i am running that program via reflection and i don't have right to change user program, so what should i do in such case?

Comment: @Addy: please tell more about your current program design, why you're using reflection, etc...

Comment: I am creating an **IDE(like Netbeans)** using swing which can compile and run user's program. if user write swing program and run the program which have `frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);` inside that program, it successfully run. but when user close there program, my IDE also get closed. How to get rid from this. I want that my IDE don't get closed.